# How to implement Umbraco 7.x website as a virtual directory in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis, iis-7, umbraco, umbraco7

I have a website developed using *Umbraco 7.3* and it's working perfectly without any problems if I installed as a website under *IIS 7.5*, the **problems started when I want to use as a virtual directory**.

### **Problems:**

1. Images not loadining in the website (404 not found)
2. 404 errors for **.CSS** files
3. 404 errors for **.JS** files

I was able to solve the 2nd and 3rd problems using the following:

- adding `<ResolveUrlsFromTextString>true</ResolveUrlsFromTextString>` under `<content>` in the **umbracoSettings.config** file in Config folder.
- I've Updated all the JS & CSS path from `"/js/*" to "~/js/*"` and `"/css/*" to "~/css/*"`.

but the 1st problem of the images still I couldn't solve, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searches, finally I was able to make it work without a single problem, following are the steps I did to implement Umbraco 7.x website as a virtual directory:

1. Open the **umbracoSettings.config** file in the **Config folder** and insert this code `<ResolveUrlsFromTextString>true</ResolveUrlsFromTextString>` between the `<content>`tag.
2. Update all of the JS & CSS paths in your main Template you are using as a master Templat from `"/js/*" to "~/js/*"` & `"/css/*" to "~/css/*"` also Add `runat="server"` attribute to the `<head>` tag or to each .CSS link in the header like this example:                                                                    `<link href="~/Css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server"/>` like the image:

[image]

3. Finally, this is the most important point, fixing the images links or the Media folder, to do this open SQL server and run the following query in the Umbraco DB`UPDATE cmsPropertyData set dataNvarchar = replace(dataNvarchar, '/media/','/replaceWithvirDirNameHer/media/')
   where dataNvarchar like '/media/%'` and don't forget to change **replaceWithvirDirNameHer** with the actual virtual directory name.
4. Restart the IIS and **republish entire site** like the image:

   [image]

### Important Note:

Some links may not reflect the changes and this is due to its path is fixed, so we need also to do them and not to forget, like the image:

[image]

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Any existing images in your content will have a path that fits your local, non-virtual directory path. But if you add images from the virtual directory it should work?

Reason is that the path is set directly in the HTML, I guess. There may be a script here to update all image paths: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/59666-Umbraco-7-in-virtual-directory

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jannik Anker, I have tried this solution but it didn't woke with my case.